# Argument error for file uploading with rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, arguments, uploading

I'm trying to set up a very basic system for uploading files to my **rails 3.1** app. Before people start throwing **paperclip** and **carrierwave** links at me, let me say that this is NOT the solution that I am looking for. I have read quiet a few posts on this topic, however, all the code I saw was either depreciated in rails 3.1 or I just did not understand how people came to a solution to this problem.

**Updated** view/form: (haml)

```
%h1 File Upload
= form_for :upload,:url=>{:action => 'uploadFile'},:html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  %p
    %label{:for => "upload_file"} Select File
    \:
    \#{f.file_field 'datafile'}
  = f.submit "Upload"
```

**Updated** controller:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
     render :file => 'upload/uploadfile.haml'
  end

  def uploadFile
    file_param = params[:upload][:datafile]
    post = DataFile.save(file_param)
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

**Updated** model

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save(upload)
    # Changed Default Destination: [__RAILS_DIR__/public/data]
    name = "public/data/" + upload.original_filename

    # can haz data directory?
    require 'FileUtils'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(name))


    File.open(name, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload.read) }
  end
end
```

**The Solution:**

Above is the correct code I used to add simple uploading functionality to my rails 3.1 app

Comment: There's a lot of details missing here. Which file does the error occur in? Which line of code? Does the controller even correctly get to `uploadFile`? Is `upload["datafile"]` even defined? Where is the `file` argument in `uploadFile` coming from?

Comment: As near as I can tell the error is occurring in data_file.rb, my only model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing unnecessary argument "file" to the uploadFile method. It's an action and passing argument to it is not possible. Just remove the "file" argument.